# Dockerfile "RUN" statement always returns non-zero

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

**Any RUN statement** in a Dockerfile **returns** a non-zero code **4294967295 (-1)** on Windows Server with *Linux containers on Windows* turned on (`LCOW_SUPPORTED = 1`)

Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:jessie
RUN exit 0
```

PowerShell output (same on cmd)

```
PS C:\docker\images\test> docker build -t test .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/2 : FROM debian:jessie
 ---> 5dd74d62fab8
Step 2/2 : RUN exit 0
 ---> Running in b8a7d0d722c8
The command '/bin/sh -c exit 0' returned a non-zero code: 4294967295
```

Same with Ubuntu Image and any other command I put after RUN.

Running *Docker17.10.0-ee-preview-3* and *Windows Server 2019 17623 prerelease.*

Comment: Interesting this is `0xFFFFFFFF`, so it could mostly be some kind of bug  in the preview. Why don't you try a non-preview version or some last stable version?

Comment: yes, as mentioned above it's -1 as signed integer. I use the preview, because I want to test the LCOW and not HyperV Linux container